# Integration variable is Imaginary and real d(Imx) , d(Rex)

Tags: integration, complex-numbers

So i have seen things like $ \int ... d(\cos x)$ and now i have an expression with $\int d\operatorname{Im}(z)$ so i though my integral would be quite straight forward, knowing the Imaginary part of $z$.

$$
z = \rho \, e^{i \theta}
$$

This is my Integral in full:
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} d\operatorname{Im}(z) 
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} d\operatorname{Re}(z) \; e^{-|z|^2} \; (z^*)^n \; z^m 
\label{imre-eqn}
\tag{1} 
\end{equation}

This is the next step, which i cant get to:
\begin{equation} 
\int_{0}^{+\infty} d\rho \; \rho^{n+m+1} \; e^{-\rho^2} \;
\int_{0}^{2\pi} d\theta \; e^{i\theta (m-n)} 
\label{exp-eqn}
\tag{2}
\end{equation}

The problem is basically that i don't know where to search to find how to get from (\ref{imre-eqn}) to (\ref{exp-eqn}). any tipp? or **what can i put into google to find out ?**

**Or, can somebody give me a more simple example of changing the integral variable from Im and Re to $\to$ what looks like spherical coordinates**

that would be fantastic thankyou!

Thanks! xyz

Answer (score 1):

You can use the identities $\Im(z)=-\frac{i}{2} (z-\bar{z})$ and $\Re(z)=\frac{1}{2}(z+\bar{z})$. You will see that $\Im(z)=\rho\sin(\theta)$ and $\Re(z)=\rho\cos(\theta)$. It should be easy from here to transform your coordinates to $(\rho,\theta)$, I hope this helps.

Comment: I have put d(ρ  cos( θ)) into the integral d- part but don't know how to resolve it.. Why is the solution just d θ  and dρ? Ι  am German and don't know how to google it in English :( how do I convert to spherical Koordinates.. Thanks for your answere x

Comment: There is a typo here. $\Im(z)=\rho\sin\theta$. Welcome Mr. Calculus; some MathJax advice - use backslashes to get special functions! If you're unsure how to render something, chances are that placing a backslash together with a sensible abbreviation will work. E.g., `\Im`, `\rho`, `\sin\theta` all render properly

Comment: Op is a struggling with the transformation itself - worth fleshing out the answer a bit more

Comment: I'm getting $\rho^{n+m\color{red}{+}1}$ and $e^{\color{red}{+}\rho^2}$ in my derivation, but I could be wrong. As for backslashes I just meant that Mr Calculus is writing `im = rho sin theta` when they should write `\Im(z)=\rho\sin\theta` @Ella

Comment: Right. How do I get to the $ /rho ^ {n+n+1} $ how do I split the d{/rho *cos / theta "}? Just into two integrals? d$/rho} d{cos/theta"}

Comment: Thanks FShrike for the typo fix. $|z|^{2}=z \bar{z}$, use that you will get the $e^{\rho^2}$ term. To split, you can get $d (\Im(z))=\rho cos(\theta) d\theta + sin(\theta) d\rho$. Do similar for $Re(z)$. Once you get that use you limits of integration to notice that $\theta$ does not change for $\Im$ part, (so conclude $d\theta$) and similar thing happen for the $\Re$ part.

Answer (score 0):

all i needed was someone to remind me that Re and Im can be drawn just like x and y in a koordinate system! And so the dIm and dRe can be translated to polar coordinates!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).